# How do I get the value of my radio input to a variable in java script

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating a game similar to that of Fenoxo's games on his blog.
Right now I'm trying to create the character creation system, the only difference with mine is it is all in javascript and HTML.

```
if (gender === 2) {
    var bodyTypeChoiceFE = "<form id='id'><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild1' value='1'>Thin<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild2' value='2'>Average<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild3' value='3'>Curvy<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild4' value='4'>Chubby<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild5' value='5'>Muscled<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild6' value='6'>Fat<br><input type='submit'></form>";
    bodyChoice = bodyTypeChoiceFE;
} else {
    var bodyTypeChoiceME = "<form id='id'><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild1' value='1'>Thin<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild2' value='2'>Average<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild4' value='4'>Chubby<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild5' value='5'>Muscled<br><input type='radio' name='BodyBuild6' value='6'>Fat<br><input type='submit'></form>";
    bodyChoice = bodyTypeChoiceME;
}

document.getElementById("charDesc").innerHTML = bodyChoice;

var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
var id_value;

if (id === "1") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild1").value;
} else if (id === "2") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild2").value;
} else if (id === "3") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild3").value;
} else if (id === "4") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild4").value;
} else if (id === "5") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild5").value;
}else if (id === "6") {
    id_value = document.getElementsByName("BodyBuild6").value;
}
```

This choice is the second choice and is based on what gender you choose, for that I use a prompt and the user types in the information.
I will probably end up using that if I can't get this to work.

if you can't be bothered to read all of this it is basically if gender is female, show the female choices
else show the male choices. then display the choices. save the value from the form if the value is 1 check the value of bodybuild1.

But this doesn't work... and I'm not sure how to make it work.
I need it so I can either save it to a variable or use the value to change the content of a variable. Either way I need the value to do something.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` returns a collection, not a single object, so `.value` doesn't exist. Change it to `getElementsByName[0].value` and try that.

Answer (score 0):

As Dai stated above: `document.getElementsByName('BodyBuild1')` returns an array of elements with the name attribute specified. If there is more than one form on the page with the same name attribute, then you need to specify which of the forms you want to target. You can do this numerically.

jQuery

```
var id_value = $('input[name="BodyBuild1"]:checked').val();
alert(id_value)
```

JavaScript

```
var id_value = document.getElementsByName('BodyBuild1')[0].checked.value;
alert(id_value)
```